# I want to use a += 1 to an argument that is outside a function, but I know using global is bad, so how do I not use global?

Tags: python

```
win = 0
loss = 0
draw = 0

def outcome():
    global win 
    global loss
    global draw
    if something:
        win += 1
    elif this:
        loss += 1
    else:
        draw += 1
    now updates the tk.Label to show the score
```

If I use return the function ends before I need to.
Outside I have a label with the counter in 0, so I need to show the counter before I use the function.

Comment: Well, if data truly is global, then you need to use globals.  You can avoid the `global` statement by making it a list: `results = [0,0,0]` / `if did_we_win():` / `results[0] += 1` / `elif did_we_lose():` / `resuts[1] += 1` and so on.

Comment: Or make a class and `outcome` as its method so that it accesses the variables like `this.win`. There might be multiple ways, which might depend on what you want to achieve in a broader context.

Comment: I have similar situations many times. What I do is the long if else logic I put in the function and give the function required inputs in your case win, loss, and draw and get required output, in your case `return [win, loss, draw]`. This will create a responsibility of function just to update variables. Hence you are now following single responsibility principle.